# I can do PUT but not POST with Spring Data Rest?

Tags: spring, rest, spring-data, spring-data-rest, hateoas

I have two simple entity like this:

```
public class Agent extends BasedEntity {

    private String firstname;

    private String lastname;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="agency_id", nullable=true)
    Agency agency;
}
```

and

```
public class Agency extends BasedEntity {

    private String name;

    private String address;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="agency")
    private Set<Agent> agents;
}

@RepositoryRestResource
public interface AgencyRespository extends JpaRepository<Agency, Long> {
}


@RepositoryRestResource
public interface AgentsRespository extends JpaRepository<Agent, Long> {
}
```

When I do a PUT with

```
https://localhost:8080/api/v1/agents/64/agency
body:https://localhost:8080/api/v1/agencies/50
```

it goes through but if I do a POST to

```
https://localhost:8080/api/v1/agents/64/agency
body:https://localhost:8080/api/v1/agencies/50
```

I get a

```
org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using an old version of Spring Data Rest. POST is allowed from 2.3.x.

The latest version is 3.2.x. You should definetely ugrade to a newer version...

----------- Edit

I've just realized that the exception is NOT the inner `HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException` from the `RepositoryPropertyReferenceController` class, but the 'default' `org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException`.

This exception is never raised directly from the SRD package.

Maybe you have a filter which deny POST request or some kind of security settings.

Comment: Im using spring-data-rest-core-3.1.11.RELEASE.jar and spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.1.11.RELEASE.jar in my classpath so thats not the cause. Any other ideas?